# regex to replace multiple characters with one

Tags: java, regex-negation

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
"abc%\%%%%"
```

I want to replace multiple `%%%` with only one `%`.  I tried something like

`String st = "abc%\%%%%".replaceAll("(%)\\1+", "$1");`

But that would also turn `"\%%"` into `"\%"`, which is not what I want. In other words, I want to replace multiple % but leave alone those preceded by a backslash.

What regex should I use?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
String st = "abc%\\%%%%".replaceAll("([%])+","$1");
       st = "Not%%%%\\%%%%sure but%%%\\%%%%%try out".replaceAll("(\\\\)([%])+","$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String st = "abc%\\%%%%";
String regex = "([\\\\]%)%+";
String result= st.replaceAll(regex,"\\\\%%");
```

result is abc%\%%

If you want to check the correctness, you can use this statement

```
 String result= st.replaceAll(regex,"\\\\%R");
```

result is abc%\%R (which confirms that % preceded by backlash is left alone.)